# swiftc produces no output and no errors

Tags: swift, linux, ubuntu

I have a simple problem:

The swift program

```
print("Hello World")
```

compiled with the command:

```
swiftc -o test test.swift
```

produces no output (no executable) and no errors.

Swift version is 4.0.2 installed in `$HOME/opt/swift/usr` on Xubuntu 17.10.

I have installed `clang` and `libicu-dev` and applied the following patches to `/etc/environment`:

```
PATH=/home/[username]/opt/swift/usr/bin:[usual PATH]
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/[username]/opt/swift/usr/lib/swift/clang/include
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$C_INCLUDE_PATH
```

Comment: Just to make sure: Did you *execute* the program after compiling it?

Comment: Nope. It dosen't give me an executable. That's the problem

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm just dumb.
At one point I must have uninstalled clang. Reinstalling it fixed everything. Although swiftc could have told me something in an error message...